# Angular 14 reactive forms addControl not working

Tags: angular

I recently migrated to Angular 14 and this line of code is throwing an exception when trying to dynamically add new from controls:

```
formGroup.addControl("agreement", new FormControl(""));
```

error:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call. 
FormControl<...>; }>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractCont
```

rol<any, any>; }>'.
....

when hovering over the line with error I get this text:

*Add a control to this group. In a strongly-typed group, the control must be in the group's type (possibly as an optional key).
If a control with a given name already exists, it would not be replaced with a new one. If you want to replace an existing control, use the FormGroup#setControl setControl method instead. This method also updates the value and validity of the control.*
Is there a workaround for this?

Please find here the problem: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v14-playground-twslcf?file=src/name.component.ts)

**UPDATE**:

This is the full code causing the problem:

```
 private test_formGroup() {
    const formGroup = new FormGroup({
      requestReference: new FormControl(''),
      emailRecipient: new FormControl([Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      emailBodyMessage: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      requestDetails: new FormControl(''),
    });

    if (true) {
      //real condition here
      formGroup.addControl('termsOfAgreement', new FormControl(''));
    }
  }
```

if I add the control at the FormGroup generation it works:

```
  const formGroup = new FormGroup({
      requestReference: new FormControl(''),
      emailRecipient: new FormControl([Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      emailBodyMessage: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      requestDetails: new FormControl(''),
      termsOfAgreement: new FormControl('')
    });

    if (true) {
      //real condition here
      formGroup.addControl('termsOfAgreement', new FormControl(''));
    }
```

but what happens when you have complex logic and you don't know from the beginning all the controls that need to be added?! what's the benefit of "addControl" if you need to specifically add it at the FormGroup creation time ?!

Comment: Can you share the code on stackblitz or github?

Comment: added stacblitz demo, you need to wait for the server to start and you'll get the error

Comment: In Angular 14 the FormGroups are now [Typed-forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't add a fromControl directly like that , you need to use the [formBuilder and formGroup](https://xpertuto.com/using-angular-formbuilder-and-formgroup/).

**method 1 :**

```
 addControl(): void {
      this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
         ...this.formGroup.controls,   // <-- push to the existing formGroup controls
         agreement: [''],
      });
    }
```

**method 2 :**

```
addControl(): void {
    this.formGroup.addControl('agreement', this.fb.control(''));
}
```

**i have fixed your code in stackblitz too :**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-name',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>, {{ name }}.
  `,
  styles: [``],
})
export class NameComponent {
  formgroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  @Input() name = '';

  private test_formGroup() {
    this.formgroup = new FormGroup({
      requestReference: new FormControl(''),
      emailRecipient: new FormControl([Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      emailBodyMessage: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      requestDetails: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.fb.group(this.formgroup);
    if (true) {
      //real condition here
      this.formgroup.addControl('termsOfAgreement', this.fb.control(''));
    }
  }
}
```

**you have no more errors :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, please have a look at the stackblitz example. it seems you need to add all the controls when you define the formgroup, you cannot add dynamically new controls

Comment: i have updated my answer , check it

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error after upgrading angular to v14. I fixed the error by using the UntypedFromGroup as explained in the docs here:

https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms

as mentioned in Eliseo's comment angular 14 now uses typed forms by default. You can fix the IDE error by using `UntypedFormGroup` like this:

```
import { FormControl, UntypedFormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

private test_formGroup() {
    const formGroup = new UntypedFormGroup({
      requestReference: new FormControl(''),
      emailRecipient: new FormControl([Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      emailBodyMessage: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      requestDetails: new FormControl(''),
    });

    if (true) {
      formGroup.addControl('termsOfAgreement', new FormControl(''));
    }
  }
```

By using a `UntypedFormGroup` the `addControl` method will work just like in angular v13

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes in your code and build the form using `FormBuilder`
Please have a look and accept the answer if this resolves your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v14-playground-zsq82f?file=src%2Fname.component.ts

Comment: I can't accept 2 answers, but yes, the FormBuilder approach works! thank you!

Comment: No problem buddy, Whatever approach helps you and is better for you proceed with that one and thanx for the upvote :)

Comment: thanks for your help, really appreaciate it